# sed escaped charcter not matching in large file

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I have large (~180MB) xml file with some wrong characters in it, for example

```
<Data ss:Type="String">7402953^@</Data>
```

The `^@` part should by removed. The job supposed to be done with

```
sed -i 's/\^@//g' /tmp/large.xml
```

but for some unknown reason it doesn't work as expected if string is located in my large xml file. If the file has only few KB in size, `sed` works perfectly.

It looks like a bug but I think it can't be because the task is quite obvious. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Why you say that is not working? Can you see `^@` in the file after its execution? If that so, try to isolate one example of the `^@` not replaced in the file, and take and small slice of the file containing that `^@`... then, make sure that is really `^@`.. probably, you have something in the middle; you could use `xxd` to be sure

Comment: A null character — if that's what it is; they appear like that — can indicate a write error, and therefore an unspecified amount (possibly more than one line) of missing data.  Use something like `grep -C 10 -Pa '\x00' large.xml` to test for null characters, and have a look at the surrounding lines of context; if there are unusually long lines or "jumps" in the file, you might have lost data during file creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by your question (because there are no examples), I would say that `^@` in the big file are not actually the two characters (`^` and `@`), but one of those unprintable characters.

You can input that unprintable character in the terminal with `Ctrl + v` + `Ctrl + 2`.
Use that in `sed` instead of the characters `^` and `@` and it should be fine.

Also remove the escape sequence because it is not needed for the unprintable character.

Comment: Yes it was actually ``\x00`` that was displayed as ``^@`` (and copied to smaller test file as such characters). The unprintable character input not worked for me (or I don't understood how to press ``Ctrl + v`` + ``Ctrl + 2``) so I just used ``sed -i 's/\x00//g' /tmp/large.xml`` and now it works as expected.

Comment: I am not sure why `Ctrl + v` followed by `Ctrl + 2` did not work. That is the default behavior for `bash` and `zsh`, so I guessed it is like that for evey shell. Maybe you were changing the keybindings or maybe you are just using some other shell that doesn't have same keybindings. Anyway, I'm glad that you solved your issue, so this is not that important now :D

Answer (score 0):

## awk

If a solution using `awk` is acceptable, this will remove all non-printable characters.

*This works in GNU awk (Linux) and BSD awk (Mac).*

```
awk '{ gsub(/[^[:print:][:blank:]]/,"",$0) ; print $0 }' input.xml > output.xml
```

- `gsub(/[^[:print:][:blank:]]/,"",$0)` 
   From each line of input, remove any unwanted characters.

  - `[:print:]` 
     Any printable character.
  - `[:blank:]` 
     Space or tab.
  - `[^[:print:][:blank:]]` 
     Any character not included in those two classes.
- `print $0` 
   Print each line of input.
- `> output.xml` 
   Save the output to a file instead of printing it to the screen.

Do the same thing with fewer keystrokes (it's just a little harder to read):

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[:print:][:blank:]]/,"")}1' input.xml > output.xml
```

- You don't need to specify `,$0` (the entire line of input) in `gsub` if you're examining the entire line.
- The `1` at the end means "now do the default action (ie, print) for every line".